# Two points on a curve that have a common tangent line

Tags: calculus

I have a curve $y = x^3 - x^4$ with an oblique common tangent line across the top of the curve. What is the equation of the tangent?

Have spent hours on this but getting no-where.

Comment: So, where exactly are you getting stuck? What approaches have you tried? Show your work so far! You might be on the right track, but just need a hint for the next step.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, $y=x^3-x^4=ax+b$ have 4 roots for $x$.
$$x^3-x^4 = ax+b \Rightarrow (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4) = 0 $$
If $ax+b$ is a tangent line on 2 points of the curve, that means

$$x^3-x^4 = ax+b \Rightarrow (x-x_1)^2(x-x_2)^2 = 0 $$

Then we can have

$$ 
x^4 - x^3 +0\cdot  x^2 + ax + b = 0 
\Rightarrow 
$$
$$
x^4 - 2(x_1+x_2)x^3 + (x_1^2+x_2^2+4x_1x_2)x^2 - 2x_1x_2(x_1+x_2)x + x_1^2x_2^2 = 0
$$

- $2x_1 + 2x_2 = 1$
- $x_1^2 + 4x_1x_2 + x_2^2 = 0$
- $-2x_1x_2(x_1+x_2) = a$
- $x_1^2x_2^2 = b$

not too hard to find $a=\frac{1}{8}$, $b=\frac{1}{64}$

[image: Plot the 2 functions below]